# Make Ping request in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, windows

so I'm very new to Visual Studio and C# but I'm having trouble making a Ping cmd in my app. I have included the code and images. Basically, when I run the app and try to make the ping request it just takes me to the `App.g.i.cs` file and highlights this code

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

So I don't know where I'm really going wrong. I know this might be a really dumb question but I'm just not familiar with Visual Studio yet. Would love any suggestions :)
Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace Ping_IP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Ping pingsender = new Ping();

            PingReply reply = pingsender.Send(ip_address.ToString());
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                status_info.Text = "Sucess! - " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();  //reply.Status.ToString();
            } else
            {
                status_info.Text = "Failed... - " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: error message]

[image: app main page]

Comment: Inspect the `e` parameter in the debugger - it will tell you what's wrong. Assuming `ip_address` is a WPF TextBox, use `ip_address.Text` to get the entered text, not `ip_address.ToString()`. You may want to set a breakpoint at your event hander and step through it to get more insight.

Comment: @KlausGütter okay thank you still the same thing but i did change it to ```ip_address.Text``` What would inspecting ```e``` look like in the code?

Comment: Disable that unhandled exception handler in debug mode. It prevents Visual Studio from recognizing the exception and stopping where the exception really happens.

Comment: You might also wrap the whole event handler in a `try...catch` and in case of an exception, write the exception message to `status_info.Text`.

Comment: @ThomasWeller okay that sounds like a great idea, I just have no idea how to do that haha. Any suggestions?

Comment: Make a multiline comment (`/* ... */`) around lines 51 to 54 or delete those lines if you have version control (which you definitely should)

Answer (score 1):

I referred to Klaus Gütter's opinion and successfully returned the data.

```
PingReply reply = pingsender.Send(ip_address.Text);
```

Complete code

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            Ping pingsender = new Ping();
            PingReply reply = pingsender.Send(ip_address.Text);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) {
                status_info.Text = "Sucess! - " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();  //reply.Status.ToString();
            } else {
                status_info.Text = "Failed... - " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
            }
        }
```

[image: Start]
[image: Clicked]

**Try catch**

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            Ping pingsender = new Ping();
            try {
                PingReply reply = pingsender.Send(ip_address.Text);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) {
                    status_info.Text = "Sucess! - " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();  //reply.Status.ToString();
                } else {
                    status_info.Text = "Failed... - " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
                }
            } catch (Exception) {
                MessageBox.Show("something wrong");
            }      
        }
    }
```

**Prompt when try fails.**

[image: TRY]

Comment: Thank you so much for this! so the `try` and `catch` works because it keeps throwing an `Exception` and I have no idea why. I do see this though
```Exception thrown: 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' in System.Net.Ping.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll```

Comment: Could you update your question with more information?

Comment: If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.